# Get client hostname

Tags: javascript

Is is possible in `javascript` to get the hostname of the client where the script is running? How?

I am **not** talking about the `url`.

Comment: No, it is not possible. Also, this question has been asked multiple times on Stack Overflow; in the future please search before posting.

Comment: (I have searched (albeit shortly), and nothing interesting popped up). Really?! That is surprising! Any rationale for that?

Comment: It poses a security risk. It is only possible through the use of Internet Explorer and an ActiveX control.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Sorry for the noise

Comment: Also possible with an applet